# save splitted pdf document to remote apache server using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm reading pdf file from remote server, splitting using pdfbox and able to save that splitted file in local system, but unable to save splitted file into the remote server. How can i do that using pdfbox.
Below is the code for splitting and saving splitted file in local system

```
        String urlPath = "http://localhost/input/"+pdfName;
String outputPath = "http://localhost/output/";
URL url = new URL(urlPath);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
document = new PDDocument();
try {
    document = PDDocument.load(is);
} catch (IOException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}

    List<PDDocument> listOfSplitPages = null;
    Splitter splitter = new Splitter();
    splitter.setStartPage(splitStartPage); // split start page
        splitter.setEndPage(splitPageNumber); // split start page
        splitter.setSplitAtPage(splitPageNumber);
        try {
            listOfSplitPages = splitter.split(document); // splitting the document
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Iterator<PDDocument> iterator = listOfSplitPages.listIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            PDDocument pdfDocument = iterator.next();
            try{
                pd.save(new FileOutputStream(outputPath+"file1.pdf"));
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Something went wrong with page \n Here is the error message" + e);                
            }            
        }

        document.close();
```

below is the Stacktrace

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\localhost\Invoices\output\file1.pdf (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1118)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.save(PDDocument.java:1106)
at Invoice.SplitPdfServlet.saveFileToRelavantFolder(SplitPdfServlet.java:174)
at Invoice.SplitPdfServlet.splitPdfUsingPageNumber(SplitPdfServlet.java:127)
at Invoice.SplitPdfServlet.doPost(SplitPdfServlet.java:81)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Show the stacktrace please. Also, how is your 'outputFileName' defined?

Comment: @VHS Edited my code

Comment: This whole question has nothing to do with PDFBox, it is a misconception how to pass files. What you could do is to save your splitted files into a zip file, and then return that one as part of your HttpServletResponse output stream with the correct type etc. (From what I see in the stack trace, you are programming the servlet)

Answer (score 1):

This is where the exception is coming in your code:

`pd.save(new FileOutputStream(outputPath+"file1.pdf"));`

You cannot write files this way over `http`. Your 'outputpath' is not a file system. When you first posted this question before your recent edits, your 'outputpath' was a local file system. I am sure it would have worked had you tried with it. The easiest solution for your problem is create a network fileshare of the remote server where you want to upload the file.

To write or upload files over http, the first thing you need is a running server handling POST requests. If you are running Apache instead, you need to some servr-side scripting to accept a file. Then you can grab the bytes from the pdf output file in a byte array and write those bytes to the remote stream.

Comment: Yeah, if i use file system, it is working fine. Thanks for the solution.I will try it.